# ColdFusion 8 query issues

Tags: coldfusion, sybase

I am using ColdFusion 8 and have query I built using SELECT Count(dog) as stuff. This works fine on one page but when I use it, changing the parameters of course, it boggs my server down. All I need is to count the items in the db tables, return how many dogs, cats, sheep, etc. and show the count and the name. Did it with the SELECT Count the first time but can't seem to get it to work this time. Is there a way I can do the same thing by not using the Count()? And forgot to mention I am using an old Sybase db...

Comment: I think we (or at least me) miss some information to understand: can you describe your table? are dogs, cats, etc... values from one column? You said it boggs your server down... what do you mean? You have to restart the CF server or you're getting an error?

Comment: the colum layout is colum 1 "dogs" colum 2 "cats" etc. It will run up to 90seconds and push the GC limits, if I let the app run I get an alert that the query is running longer than expected do I want to stop the query... Now the colum "dogs" contains "bull", "shepard", etc.I need a count of how many types of dogs are in the colum, how many cats, etc.

Comment: the one that works is <cfquery name="getstuff" datasource="mydatabase" timeout="30"> Select count(cars) as mycount, cars from allcars </cfquery> it returns an output of all the cars and how many "fords", "Chevys", etc. I am trying to do the same thing with a different table in the same db. <cfquery name="getpetstuff" datasource="mydatabase" timeout="30"> Select count(dogscars) as mycount, dogs from allpets </cfquery>

Comment: Use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11465406/edit) to put all that information in the question!

Answer (score 0):

can't you do the following...

```
<cfquery name="getpetstuff" datasource="mydatabase" timeout="30">
Select dogs, count(*) as mycount 
  from allpets
group by dogs
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can take the return of the query without the select count and achieve the same results?

Comment: Nothing I can think about. Is it you who put the timeout at 30 sec? Maybe you have an index problem on that table. Try ordering first to see if it will improve it: add order by dogs

Comment: Thanks guys but I found my problem... it was an order by... was trying to count and order by asc. Once I removed the asc all works fine. Another question though? Can I have more than one count in my select statement?

Answer (score 0):

Adding indexes to tables will solve many performance problems in MS-SQL which has it's roots in Sybase.

Try adding an index that just contains the dogs in the allpets table.

Comment: It is unfortunate that I have asked the db admins about this and they ignore me... I wish they would index because the db is running slower than it should. Thanks for the advise, I will keep squeeking!